# Three-bulb defusal dilemma

Tags: logical-deduction

Here's a fun riddle I thought I'd share with you all:

You are an American military soldier who needs to defuse a catastrophic explosive set to go off in five minutes. You can do this by deactivating at most one of three switches on an electrical panel and deactivating more than one would set off an equally devastating explosion on the other side of the city you're in that you can't get to in time, and you have a working flashlight in hand to help you:

The switch linked to the explosive in question is also linked to an incandescent light bulb in a 6-foot-tall lamp at the back of a closed, windowless/sunroofless chamber that you can only enter at most once. How would you make sure you save the city (you must factor in the time you take to think through this problem into the time you have left to defuse it as if you were the soldier who received this information right when a 5 minute timer started)?

Comment: This is not a proper duplicate of the linked question.  Unlike in the other problem, two switches need to be on at all times.   In the solution given in the link, two switches must be off at the same time.